# How to break out the due power supply and USB connectors?

Tags: arduino-due

I am planning a build with my own enclosure for the arduino due. As an alternative i would like to bypass the power jack and usb port that are factory soldered onto the board, in order to use jacks mounted on the enclosure, along with a power switch.

I've looked at the info regarding the boards pin configuration at https://www.arduino.cc/en/pmwiki.php?n=Main/arduinoBoardDue, and would appreciate if someone could confirm or correct this:

1. Can i use an external 9V adapter through a jack connected to the Vin and GND pins, respectively?
2. According to [This question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/47480/are-pins-0-and-1-rx-and-tx-parallel-with-the-usb-jack-can-i-connect-another-u), you can't connect an alternative programming USB port to Serial 0 TX/RX pins (Mega board). If this applies to the due as well, what do i need to break out the programming USB port?

Edit: Perhaps [one of these puppies](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3258) is the least complicated solution?

Comment: You can't connect a USB socket or USB cable - but you can connect an FT232 adapter cable / board.

Comment: your `Edit` is the answer ... use pigtails for all connections ... insert a switch into the power pigtail

Comment: you could reprogram the ATmega16U2 to existing programming port and release the serial0 pins for your use ... or use the ATmega16U2 as a serial port gateway between JP5 and serial0

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for your input!

Comment: the first part of my comment sounds like nonsense ... i did not proofread it ... it should say something like `you could reprogram the ATmega16U2 to stop being the programming port and release the serial0 pins for your use`

Answer (score 1):

so 1 - yes. the VIN pin has a common trace with the barrel jack, you can verify with a multimeter in continuity/beep mode. ive actually put power out through the barrel jack on a mega.

2- i cant find a clear schematic for the due at the moment, but on the mega the rx/tx pins are also common with the usb pins, thus they are not usable while plugged into usb